# How to disable operations queue in Node.js MondoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm simply using this code to write to MongoDB:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl,function(error,db){
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    var dbo = db.db(mongoDatabase);
    dbo.collection(myCollection).insertOne(item, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close()
    })
})
```

If i execute the code above for only one insert, all goes ok.
But if i want to execute many inserts, for example if i call the code above in a loop statement, the real writes occurs all at one time at the end of the loop.

For example if i call the code above in a 100 cycles loop, the 100 inserts occurs all at same time after the 100th cycle. The big problem is that when the inserts occurs, many connections to MongoDB are opened at the same time, and if i pass the max files opened OS limit i have also the "Too many opened files" error.

I know i can use bulkWrite and insertMany operations, but i want only to know if there is a way to have the real writes occurs in database after each insertOne, and not at the end of the loop.

It seems that there's some sort of queue managed by the MongoClient that waits for an similar operation on the same collection to occur, and in this case it collect all these operations to do them all at one time. I want simply to avoid this and make each operation occurs at real time.

---

Update - 10 October 2018

If i call the code posted above with the following code

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}

drawModel.saveDraw({test: "1"})
sleep(2000)
drawModel.saveDraw({test: "1"})
sleep(2000)
drawModel.saveDraw({test: "1"})
sleep(2000)
drawModel.saveDraw({test: "1"})
sleep(2000)
drawModel.saveDraw({test: "1"})
sleep(2000)
```

during the code execution i don't see any changes in the database, and in the mongo console also i don't see any write occurs. I insert 2 seconds sleeps to have the time to verify this while the code is executing.
At the end of the last sleep, all the writes occurs at the same time.

```
2018-10-10T15:44:25.649+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54855 #5 (5 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.649+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54856 #6 (6 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.649+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54857 #7 (7 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.649+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54858 #8 (8 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.649+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:54859 #9 (9 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.658+0200 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:54855 (8 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.658+0200 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:54856 (7 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.658+0200 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:54857 (6 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.658+0200 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:54858 (5 connections now open)
2018-10-10T15:44:25.659+0200 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:54859 (4 connections now open)
```

As you can see, the concurrent writes causes concurrent connections, and consequent concurrent file opening. I want to avoid this and make the writes occurs at real time.

Comment: reuse the connection, create a Promise that resolves the connection and each time you need the connection just do `getConnectionPromise.then(db => {... })`

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general thing about node programming in general. Everything is run in a single thread, callbacks are run after your loop, this is using callback API; to serialize your operations one by one you need to put the next operation inside the callback for the previous. You cannot use a loop like for or while. You have to write a recursive function to serialize operations. Which is where the batch functions come in to simplify things for you

If you use promise style API with newer versions of node you will be able to use async await syntax and write what would look like synchronous code with loops

EDIT:

When I said you couldn't do it with a loop I didn't mean just write out your loop actions manually. I meant that to ensure your operations are completed one at a time (that is serialized) you need to put the next action into callback for the previous action. For example, you have three functions that do things asynchronously - with callback API they take a callback argument which is the last argument by convention. To make sure these three things happen in sequence you need to write code like this:

```
function doThings (callback) {
  firstThing(argsForFirstThing, function (error, resultOfFirstThing) {
    if (error) console.log(err)
    else secondThing(argsForSecondThing, function (error, resultOfSecondThing) {
      if (error) console.log(err)
      else thirdThing(argsForThirdThing, callback)
    }
  }
}
```

To do an indeterminate number of things in sequence you will need to write a recursive function or take a look at the `async` package from npm

EDIT2:

Regarding the code you posted; NodeJS is a single threaded event dispatcher. A single batch of code will run to completion and the callbacks will happen only after that. Do not block your code like that as the callbacks will obviously not execute until you relinquish control

If you actually want to wait you need do use `setTimeout` like this:

```
// .. do stuff
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('the rest of your code here after 2 seconds')
}, 2000)
```

In your example let's assume `saveDraw` looks like this:

```
saveDraw(options, callback) {
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl,function(error,db){
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    var dbo = db.db(mongoDatabase);
    dbo.collection(myCollection).insertOne(item, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close(callback)
    })
})
```

Note the callback parameter passed to close. Then your calling code should look like this:

```
saveDraw({test: '1'}, (err) => {
  saveDraw({test: '2'}, (err) => {
    saveDraw({test: '3'} (err) => {
      console.log('I saved 3 things')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I also tried to execute the code in the first post  without loops.

Comment: Can you post your recursive function?

Comment: But...if i put a console.log just before the MongoClient.connect, the log shows every two seconds as expected. Instead a log inside the callback of MongoClient.connect is shown at the end of all the writes at the same instant.
May be this not a general Javascript behaviour but specific to the way MongoClient.connect handles the connections ?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't mean anything, that's an implementation detail. The API is callback meaning they reserve to use it asynchronously or not. If you use it synchronously you are bound to see issues you're seeing